# Comparing floor and roof areas using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, layers, fields-attributes, area

I am trying to show the available roof area for installing photovoltaic moduls in comparison to the respective floor area in QGIS.
I have two vector layers so far. One contains the floor area of the houses, the second one the appropriate roof areas. All I want is the amount of roof area in percent (or at least in m²) of their respective floor area. Important is, that only the roof areas that sit in the floor areas shall be involved. As you can see in the picture below, some of the roof areas are bigger then the floor areas. I thought this problem would be very easy to solve, even for a newbie like me, but i could not handle this yet.

So you can better imagine the problem, a screenshot of how it looks like:

[image: Setup]

Comment: Do the layers contain any attributes? Like house ids? Or do you have to rely on the geometries for your analysis?

Comment: Yes the layers contain attributes. The floor araes layer contains: AREA, PERIMETER, address and a lot more other attributes that don't seem to be necessary. The roof areas layer contains: AREA, PERIMETER, roof pitch and roof oriantation both in degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your goal

> percent of roof area of their respective floor area (only the roof areas that sit in the floor areas)

I suggest the following steps:

1. add a column with the floor area to the floor layer if it doesn't exist
2. intersect the roof layer with the floor layer
3. add a column with the intersection area to the intersection result layer
4. compute the percentage as `intersection area / floor area`